# zero raised to infinity

Tags: infinity, exponentiation

I encountered a question where the only condition stated that $t>0$ and was then asked to compare these two quantities

1. $0^t$
2. $t^0$

The scope of $t$ is $(0,\infty)$ and hence for infinity 1.) and 2.) are not defined . However the answer states that 2.) > 1.) as 1.) would always be zero .
Is that the correct explanation?

Comment: $\infty$ is not in $(0,\infty)$. Thus your question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

$0^t=0 \lt 1 = t^0$ for all $t \in (0,\infty)$.

So the answer would be correct if it showed $t^0$ was positive.

Comment: $ o^{0}=1 $ since $ x^{x}=e^{xln(x)} $ and $ x \to 0 $ $ xln(x)=1 $

Comment: @JoseGarcia: $0 \not \in (0, \infty)$

Comment: @JoseGarcia: With the same right I can say $0^0 = \lim_{x\to 0+0}0^x = \lim_{x\to 0+0}0 = 0$. You simply cannot unambiguously determine $0^0$ as limit because $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. However for many problems it is meaningful to *define* $0^0=1$, for example so you can write polynomials as $\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ without making a special case either for the term $a_0$ or for the value $x=0$.